# Initialize reference member in class C++

Tags: c++, class

I have a class in which I have a reference member as follows:

**SampleClass.h**

```
class SampleClass{
public:
SampleClass(bool mirror=false);
void updateFunction(); 
private:
BodyTrackeDevice _device;
BodyBlob& _userBody;
BodyMuscle _muscle;
bool _mirror;
};
```

**SampleClass.cpp**

```
SampleClass::SampleClass(bool mirror)
{
this->_mirror = mirror;
}
```

> Error: Constructor for `SampleClass` must explicitly initialize the reference member `_userBody`

which is obvious because what I should have done to initialise the reference member should have been

```
SampleClass::SampleClass(bool mirror, BodyBlob& bodyBlob) : _userBody(bodyBlob){
...
}
```

However, `BodyBlob&` is something that I'll be getting from `BodyTrackerDevice` as `BodyTrackerDevice.getTrackedBody[0]` and is not something that I can pass to the constructor of the class. What is the right approach followed here to get rid of the error?

Comment: Use a pointer instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

References are basically like pointers, but with two very important difference: a) they must be initialized when created (in order to minimize the possibility of having a dangling references in contrast to a dangling pointer), and b) cannot change the object they point to.

In your code, you have the needs that maybe can be covered by b), but not for a)(you say you'll get the value for _userBody "later", not in the time of building the object), so the you've only two possibilities left: use a simple object (which you can initialize by copying the new value) [not very good], or just use a pointer instead of a reference.

```
class SampleClass {
public:
    SampleClass(bool mirror=false);
    void updateFunction(); 
private:
    BodyTrackeDevice _device;
    BodyBlob * _userBody;
    BodyMuscle _muscle;
    bool _mirror;
};

SampleClass::SampleClass(bool mirror)
{
    this->_mirror = mirror;
}

void SampleClass::updateFunction()
{
    _userBody = &( device.getTrackedBody[ 0 ] );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Class members are initialised in the order of their declaration. This means that by the time `_userBody` initialisation starts, `_device` is already initialised and you can do this:

```
SampleClass::SampleClass(bool mirror)
  : _userBody(_device.getTrackedBody[0])
  , _mirror(mirror)
{ ::: }
```

An alternative to consider would be to use a pointer instead of a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to just initialize your variable from another one in your initialization list. You can put an expression in there `: _userBody(BodyTrackerDevice.getTrackedBody[0]) { }`
Or you can even call a function to return the value you want to initialize it with if it's not a simple value  `: _userBody(getMyData()) {}`

Answer (score 0):

just use a pointer instead:

```
class SampleClass{
public:
    SampleClass(bool mirror=false);
    void updateFunction(); 
private:
    BodyTrackeDevice _device;
    BodyBlob* _userBody;
    BodyMuscle _muscle;
    bool _mirror;
};
```

reference has to be always initialized in a constructor. Sometimes you can initialized it with some initial value, say

```
_userBody(userBody())
```

and later change for something suitable, using for example

```
void setUserBody(BodyBlob& b){
    _userBody=b;    
}
```

but using a pointer doesn't also harm you and maybe even gives you more flexibility.
[here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html) you can find more about initializations & constructors